# Band Structure from EIGENVAL in VASP

Tags: density-functional-theory, vasp, band-structure, python

So I am trying to plot the band structure from the `EIGENVAL` file produced by VASP. I wrote this Python code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as mpl

mpl.rcParams["mathtext.fontset"] = "stix"   # Change the math font
mpl.rcParams["font.family"] = "STIXGeneral" # Change the global font

with open('EIGENVAL', 'r') as f:
    data = f.readlines()

nkpts = int(data[5].split()[1])
nbands = int(data[5].split()[2])

print(nkpts, nbands)

kpoints = []
energies = []
for i in range(nkpts):
    line_index = 7+(nbands+2)*i
    kpoint_coords = [float(x) for x in data[line_index].split()[:3]]
    eigenvalues = []
    for j in range(nbands):
        eigenvalue = float(data[line_index+j+1].split()[1])
        eigenvalues.append(eigenvalue)
    kpoints.append(kpoint_coords)
    energies.append(eigenvalues)

kpoints = np.array(kpoints)
energies = np.array(energies)

EF = 1.92675163
energies = (energies.T - EF).T

xaxis = [j for j in range(len(kpoints))]

mpl.xticks([xaxis[0], xaxis[int(len(xaxis)/2-1)], xaxis[-1]], ["L", "Γ", "X"])
for i in range(nbands):
    mpl.plot(xaxis, energies[:, i])
mpl.axhline(y=0, linestyle='--')
# mpl.axhline(y=2, linestyle='--')
mpl.axvline(x=xaxis[0], linestyle='-')
mpl.axvline(x=xaxis[int(len(xaxis)/2-1)], linestyle='-')
mpl.axvline(x=xaxis[-1], linestyle='-')
mpl.xlabel('$k$-points')
mpl.ylabel('$E$$-$VBM [eV]')
mpl.savefig('BS.png', dpi=800, bbox_inches="tight")
mpl.show()
```

I am getting this figure:
[image]

I am defining the `xaxis` array which is rather arbitrary.

**My question is: Is there a more efficient way to plot the band structure after extracting the data?**

Comment: Are you looking for ways to plot the band structure using the EIGENVAL file? Or is it okay if you get the plot using other VASP output files? If it is the latter case: see [this](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/1988/what-are-some-good-band-structure-dos-plotting-tools-styles) and [this](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/364/what-are-the-pre-post-processing-tools-available-for-vasp/383) question where you can find many post-processing tools. (The link to sumo is broken in the question. [This](https://smtg-ucl.github.io/sumo/sumo-bandplot.html) is working)

Comment: Could you please clarify in your question what you mean by “better way to plot band structure”?  what is your expected output of the plot?

Comment: Thanks so much @AbdulMuhaymin. This answers my question.

Comment: @Mohamed in that case, I will try to add it as an answer.

Comment: @AbdulMuhaymin very useful links, I had also tried in the past to extract by parsing the data of the vasp.xml file for a plot using gnuplot, but this is stuff already done and more efficiently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @AbdulMuhaymin pointed out in the comments: [PyPROCAR](https://romerogroup.github.io/pyprocar/index.html) looks like a nice tool that does more than just plotting band structures, and it works for many DFT codes other than VASP.